# Getting gapi Calendar events by start and end date not working

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-calendar-api

I'm trying to get all the events from my calendar between 2014-03-31 and 2014-04-07 and put those dates in my request. It gives me a whopping 250 events however, in which the first is from 2012-02-20.

The only thing I can think about is that it's ignoring my start and end filter. Did I made a typo, used to wrong parameters or what's up?

```
function getEvents(calendarId) {
    gapi.client.load('calendar', 'v3', function() {
        var request = gapi.client.calendar.events.list({
            calendarId: calendarId,
            start: '2014-03-31',
            end: '2014-04-07'
        });

        request.execute(function(resp) {
            console.log(resp.items.length);
        });
    });
}
```

I've tried formatting as following aswell to no avail:

```
"start": {
    "date": date
}
```

Answer (score 0):

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/list

The api documentation specifies datetime parameters - maybe it's not clever enough to automatically convert the strings to valid dates, try:

```
function getEvents(calendarId) {
    gapi.client.load('calendar', 'v3', function() {
        var request = gapi.client.calendar.events.list({
            calendarId: calendarId,
            start: new Date("2014-03-31").toISOString(),
            end: new Date("2014-04-07").toISOString()
        });

        request.execute(function(resp) {
            console.log(resp.items.length);
        });
    });
}
```